# Understanding Average Velocity's Logic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

Firstly, I'm a new learner of physics. I'm a bit confused about average Velocity's logic. There is a problem that I am trying to solve as the following :

> You walk $73.2$ m at a speed of $1.22$ m/s and then run $73.2$ m at a speed of $3.05$ m/s along a straight track. What is the average velocity?

I'm trying to think how should I consider the problem in terms of what?
If you explain it with words, I appreciate you :)

Comment: Average velocity is defined as total distance divided by total time. So determine what the total distance and the total time are, and you're essentially done. The pitfall with problems like the one you stated is that some people start trying to figure out how to directly average the given speeds to get the answer, and that often leads to problems.

Comment: Total displacement over total time.   Not distance

Comment: @SamuelWeir, isn't that an answer (even if not quite correct) rather than a comment?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - I guess that I thought that it was such a trivial question about a definition (i.e., average velocity) that just a quick comment was more appropriate.

Comment: @ggcg - Yes, you're right. I should have written "total displacement" rather than "total distance".

Comment: Your answer made sense relative to the OP question but you want to be exact for when they apply it to a circle.  Average speed versus average velocity, they convey different information.

Comment: @SamuelWeir, noted. Note that I'm simply following the guidelines found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/9887):  *"Whenever you see someone post something as a comment that seems like it should be an answer, ask them to make it an answer. Or post it as an answer yourself. (It'd be good etiquette to give the commenter a chance to convert their comment into an answer first, but you have no obligation to do so. And it's good for the site to have things that are answers posted as answers.)"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average velocity=total displacement  /total time time

Here total time is 73.2/1.22=$y$,  and 73.2/3.05=$x$,

Now total distance is 2.(73.2)/($y$+$x)$=gives you average velocity.